# Ignoring symbols and select only numerical values with pandas

Tags: python, data-cleaning, pandas

In one field I have entries like 'U$ 192,0'. Working on pandas, how I ignore non numerical data and get only the numerical part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str.strip` if the prefix is fixed or `str.replace` if not:

```
data = pandas.Series(["U$ 192.0"])
data.str.replace('^[^\d]*', '').astype(float)
```

This removes all the non-numeric characters to the left of the number, and casts to float.

Comment: But , for large data sets this would be considerably slow , wouldn't? There is no built-in function on pandas for doing it?

Comment: These are built in functions :) It should be as fast as anything else you can do in pandas? If the data is in a file you could preprocess it with a command line utility. You should specify what your input is; file, db, etc.

Comment: Oh sorry , Itoght it was RE. And it seems that some of data the cents are separated with , rather then . and is returning the fallowing error 'ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 300,00 ' , how to handle it?

btw, the input is a file

Comment: Something like `str.replace('^[(^\d]*(\d+)[.,](\d+)', '\1.\2')`